# Consulta muchos a muchos en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buenos días compañeros.

Reago la pregunta porque creo que no me he expliado con total claridad.

Tengo el siguiente ERD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada usuario registrado gestiona sus propias entidades que tendrán N departamentos y N niveles. Cada departamentos podrá contener muchos niveles o viceversa.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, he realizado la siguiente consulta mediante la cuál obtengo todos los niveles de la entidad que pertenece a un usuario en concreto.

```
$hierarchies = DB::table('clients')
        ->rightJoin('hierarchies', 'clients.id', '=', 'hierarchies.client_id')
        ->select('hierarchies.*', 'clients.company')
        ->where('clients.user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();
```

Lo que quiero conseguir ahora, es añadir los departamentos que están relacionados con los distintos niveles.

Con esta otra consulta obtengo los departamentos y sus correspondientes niveles relacionados pero como podría hacer para que fueran solo los concernientes a los clientes de un usuario en concreto.

```
$departments = Department::with('departmentsHierarchies')
        ->where('client_id', $id)
        ->orderBy('departmentname', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

En los respectivos modelos tengo creadas las siguientes relaciones:

```
public function hierarchiesDepartments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class);
}

public function departmentsHierarchies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hierarchie::class);
}
```

¿Cómo podría obtener los departamentos de los distintos niveles teniendo en cuenta la consulta anterior donde se filtra por el usuario?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: En teoría sería solo agregar el método `with('departmentsHierarchies')` a tu consulta.

Comment: Hola gaidyjg. ¿Pero directamente a la consulta join que ya tengo elaborada?

Comment: Sí, solo haces `DB::table('clients')->with('departmentsHierarchies')...get([ /* Array de columnas a escoger */ ]);`

Comment: Hola BetaM. Tienes razón. existe la tabla clients que no aparece en la relación indicada. El motivo es que debo filtar lo niveles por cliente y cada cliente o clientes pertenece a un único usuairo. Por este motivo incluyo la tabla clients para obtener solo aquellos registros que pertenecen a los clientes del usuario que está logado. En la consulta, lo que obtengo son los niveles (hierarchies) de los clientes que pertenecen al usuario logado. No sé si es la forma más óptima de hacerlo. ¿qué me aconsejas?. Gracias

Comment: users 1:N clients, clients 1:N departments, clients 1:N hierarchies, departments N:M hierarchies. Este sería el esquema de tablas general actualmente.

Comment: Perfecto. Acabo de rehacer la pregunta. Creo que no me explique demasiado bien. Gracias.

Comment: quiere hacer inner join al select (obtener datos en una misma consulta de una tabla adyacente) para agregar los departamento relacionados a los clientes?